# transfer every integer of a given matrix to another number system and calculate its length

Tags: matlab, matrix

This has bothered me for a while. Let A be a given integer matrix. I need to transfer each element of A into another number system with base 6 and put the length of the transferred into the corresponding entry. For example, is the input is:

```
 1     5     9    13
 2     6    10    14
 3     7    11    15
 4     8    12    16
```

The expected output would be:

```
 1  1  2  2
 1  2  2  2
 1  2  2  2
 1  2  2  2
```

Suppose the original matrix is a. I tried `dec2base(a,6)`, which gives me a vector instead of a matrix.

```
01
02
03
04
05
10
11
12
13
14
15
20
21
22
23
24
```

After checking, this is a 16 by 2 vector. You can see that the output has already added a 0 automatically to make it neat. But this is not what I want. I believe I can do it, by define a self-written function which applies to a single value first and then to use the arrayfun operation. I was just wondering, is ther a better way to do this? Many thaks for your time and attention.

Comment: I already solved this by arrayfun. It is actually not time-consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `arrayfun` to apply a function to every element of an array. The output in this case will be a cell array. This one you can convert back into a matrix wit `cell2mat`.

```
a = [1     5     9    13;
     2     6    10    14;
     3     7    11    15;
     4     8    12    16];

 b = arrayfun(@(x)length(dec2base(x,6)),a,'UniformOutput',false);

 c = cell2mat(b)
```

Gives you the following output:

```
c =
     1     1     2     2
     1     2     2     2
     1     2     2     2
     1     2     2     2
```

Answer (score 2):

That can be done just with logarithms. Let

```
A = [ 1     5     9    13
      2     6    10    14
      3     7    11    15
      4     8    12    16 ];
b = 6;
```

Then

```
result = floor(log(A)/log(b))+1;
```

Comment: quick and smart idea. I like it. Thanks, Luis.